# Получить width экрана css

Tags: css, css3, viewport

Мне необходимо настроить `@viewport` в CSS вот таким образом:

```
@viewport {
    min-zoom: (width / 14.4) / 100;
    user-zoom: fixed;
}
```

Где width - ширина экрана браузера. 
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=%40viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй вместо width написать 100vw, хотя, очень странное у тебя написание медиавыражения, даже сложно представит для какого устройства ты такое пытаешься запустить

Comment: http://www.webmolot.com/viewport/